# Light fixture to ceiling which has 2 green wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

My ceiling box has 2 green wires and one each of black and white. While my light fixture only has one green.

How and where do I connect the green wires?

Comment: where do the green wires travel?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Answer (score 1):

### Connect the green wires to each other and to the fixture green

Since we already have hot and neutral accounted for, those green wires must be grounding wires, and thus need to be connected together; an ordinary wirenut or lever-lock ("Wago") connector will do the trick, depending on what's used in your area.